# Adding boolean values in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I want to add a simple boolean value in my JSX. It is just a flag to say something is active or not.

```
<NavItem href="#/gosomewhere" active >
```

I am unsure how to pass in the 'active' flag in JSX.

I thought this would work fine :

```
const active= location.pathname.match(/^\/gosomewhere/) ? "active" : "";

return(

                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#/gosomewhere" {active} >
                    Go Somewhere
                </NavItem>
)
```

However I get this error :

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ...
```

Do I somehow need to use the spread operator in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass boolean values the same way as other props, simply use `active={true|false}`:

```
const active = location.pathname.match(/^\/gosomewhere/);
return(
   <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#/gosomewhere" active={active} >
     Go Somewhere
   </NavItem>
)
```

Comment: is active=true equivalent to just 'active' ?

Comment: @OliverWatkins yes, it is just shortcut in jsx

Answer (score 1):

Answer to "is active=true equivalent to just 'active' ?"

Yes, `active={true}` is equivalent to `active`. Just marking `active` is recommanded as by the [W3C recommandation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)

I'm posting this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Although it is recommended in html tags, in general it is not recommended in jsx. I mean it depends on what you need to do